# Auto scroll table up and down in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have table which has multiple row and is scrollable. I have been trying to add a functionality of automatic vertical scrolling for the table once component loads, so user does not have to scroll manually. Below is the work I have done so far.

```
    componentDidMount() {
 
      var tableContainer = document.querySelector("tbody");

      function autoScroller(){
          var sTop = tableContainer.scrollTo(top);
          var sDown = tableContainer.scrollHeight - tableContainer.clientHeight;
          tableContainer.animate({scrollTop:sTop < sDown/2 ? sDown : 0}, 4000, autoScroller);
      }
      autoScroller();
   }
    
   render(){

   return(

            <div className="tableContainer">
               <table className="table table-striped table-dark">
                    <thead>
                       <tr>
                        <th>Table Header</th>
                      </tr>
                     </thead>   
                        <tbody>
                          <tr><td>row 1</td></tr>
                          <tr><td>row 2</td></tr> 
                          <tr><td>row 3</td></tr> 
                          <tr><td>row 4</td></tr> 
                          <tr><td>row 5</td></tr> 
                          <tr><td>row 6</td></tr> 
                          <tr><td>row 7</td></tr> 
                          <tr><td>row 8</td></tr>       
                        </tbody> 
                  </table>   
              </div>

   )
   }
```

And CSS

```
table thead tr th{

  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}

.tableContainer {  
  height:20vh ;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 15px;

}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

Something like this might work:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Table.css';
import $ from 'jquery';

export default class Table extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.containerRef = React.createRef();
    this.interval = null;
    this.scrollIndex = 0;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.startScrolling();
  }

  startScrolling() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      const container = this.containerRef.current;
      if (container === null) return;
      
      const containerHeight = container.clientHeight;

      const rows = container.querySelectorAll("tr");
      const nChildren = rows.length;
      const rowHeight = rows[0].clientHeight;

      const theadHeight = container.querySelector("thead").clientHeight;

      const nRowsVisible = Math.floor(containerHeight / rowHeight);
      this.scrollIndex = this.scrollIndex + nRowsVisible >= nChildren ?
        0 :
        this.scrollIndex + nRowsVisible

      // Jquery animate is a bit smoother than scrollTo, but either works
      // container.scrollTo({top: this.scrollIndex * rowHeight - theadHeight, behavior: "smooth"});
      $(container).animate({scrollTop: this.scrollIndex * rowHeight - theadHeight}, 1000);
    }, 4000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="tableContainer" ref={this.containerRef}>
        <table className="table table-striped table-dark">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Table Header</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr><td>row 1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row 3</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row 4</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row 5</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row 6</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row 7</td></tr>
            <tr><td>row 8</td></tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    )
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table thead tr th{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}

.tableContainer {  
  height:20vh ;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin-bottom: 15px;

}
```

I had the same use-case and first implemented it with the approach above.
I later needed a more continuous/looped scroll which I ended up implementing  w/ CSS animations (implementation can be seen [here](https://github.com/JamieBeverley/react-auto-scroll-table/blob/daa4461b57c14854ba1e04e9e66dcfe647ca2970/react-auto-scroll-table/src/index.tsx)).

I just published a react component to `npm` if it might fit your needs: [react-auto-scroll-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-auto-scroll-table). Demo and usage notes [here](https://jamiebeverley.github.io/react-auto-scroll-table/)

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.